# Let $a \in G$. Show that for any $g \in G$, $gC(a)g^{-1} = C(gag^{-1})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

> Let $a \in G$. Show that for any $g \in G$, $gC(a)g^{-1} = C(gag^{-1})$.

Note that $C(a) = \left \{g \in G : ag = ga \; or\; gag^{-1} = a\right \} $.

How do I begin such a problem? I thought about letting $ghg^{-1}\in gC(a)g^{-1}$. But I am not sure what to do afterwards.

Comment: Try checking if the element $ghg^{-1}$ you thought of is in $C(gag^{-1})$ and then vice versa.

Comment: @Cornelius I tried doing this but I am not sure exactly what the elements in $C(gag^{-1})$ look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard "trick" for showing $A = B$ for sets $A, B$ is $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$. We will employ that.

$\newcommand{\gi}{g^{-1}}
\newcommand{\bi}{b^{-1}}
\newcommand{\xi}{x^{-1}}
\newcommand{\seq}{\subseteq}$

Let $b = gx\gi \in gC(a)\gi$. Then $b(ga\gi)\bi = (bg)a(bg)^{-1} = gxa\xi\gi = ga\gi$ as $xa\xi = a$. So $b \in C(ga\gi)$. Since $b$ was general, $gC(a)\gi \subseteq C(ga\gi)$.

Now lets use another trick. We will not prove the other direction explicitly. Instead lets use the result we just proved.

$gC(a)\gi \seq C(ga\gi)$. Put $a = \gi c g$. So $gC(\gi cg)\gi \seq 
 C(c)$. So $C(\gi c g) \seq \gi C(c) g$, which is the reverse direction.

This is a standard trick that works in groups because of the bijective properties of the product.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks for taking the time to help me. May I ask why $(bg)a(bg)^{-1}=gxax^{-1}g^{-1}$?

Comment: $b = gxg^{-1} \implies bg = gx$.